# How to conditionally update a table in R?

Tags: r

My table looks like this:

```
#      Year    Month    WaterYear
#      1993      3
#      2000      4
#      2013      10
#      2015      6
#      2000      7
#      2008      12
#      2008      9
#      2012      10
#      2000      11
#      2000      12
```

I am trying to update this table by computing WaterYear equals Year+1 where months range between October and December.

I am working on R and hoping to find the easiest way to make it work.

Comment: Try `which(cond, arr.ind=TRUE)`, where `cond` is your condition.

Answer (score 3):

Simple `ifelse` function will do the trick. 
From your data.

```
# Create data
Year <- c(1993, 2000, 2013, 2015, 2000, 2008, 2008, 2012, 2000, 2000)
Month <- c(3, 4, 10, 6, 7, 12, 9 ,10, 11, 12)
WaterYear <- rep("",length(Year))

dat <- data.frame(Year, Month, WaterYear)

# If month is greater or equal to 10 change it to Year +1, 
# otherwise keep it as it is

dat$WaterYear <- ifelse(dat$Month >=10, Year+1, WaterYear)
```

Results in

```
Year Month WaterYear
1993     3          
2000     4          
2013    10      2014
2015     6          
2000     7          
2008    12      2009
2008     9          
2012    10      2013
2000    11      2001
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is the function I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
i1 <- dat$Month >=10
dat$WaterYear[i1] <- dat$Year[i1] + 1
dat
#   Year Month WaterYear
#1  1993     3          
#2  2000     4          
#3  2013    10      2014
#4  2015     6          
#5  2000     7          
#6  2008    12      2009
#7  2008     9          
#8  2012    10      2013
#9  2000    11      2001
#10 2000    12      2001
```

---

Or using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dat)`), specify the logical condition in 'i' (`Month >= 10`), and assign (`:=`) the 'Year' + 1 to 'WaterYear'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[Month >=10, WaterYear := as.character(Year + 1)]
```